# pip not showing in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

pip comes pre-installed with python. So when I installed python and went on to check the scripts folder after the installation , pip was already there. But when I ran pip from cmd nothing showed up. Please help. Thanks in advance.[image: on]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
python -m pip
```

or

```
python3 -m pip  (depending on your python path)
```